# How to check coroutine list when debugging android app or android test in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Why is it that when running on an android device, such as running `androidtest`, my debugger can't find the coroutine panel. but when running `test`, it can find the coroutine panel?

android studio version:

```
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1
Build #AI-232.10227.8.2321.11479570, built on February 22, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0--11185874 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

[image: no coroutine panel found]

[image: coroutine panel found in yellow box]